# Change the colors of a texture based on another texture in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, pixel, texture2d

So I´m trying to use the function GetPixels basically to change the colors of a second texture based on the pixel colours of a first (or source) texture.

I didn´t try much, I was looking for ways to approach this or get some documentation but Unity Scripting API is pretty messed up.

So far, I´ve got a pseudocode that isn´t working at all, if any of ya could help to get it working that would be really nice.

```
var secondTexture = new Texture2D(width, height);
Texture2D source = sourceTexture;

var pixels = new Color[width * height];
for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
   for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
            Color pixels2 = source.GetPixels(x, y);

            if(pixels2 == Color.white)
            {
              //Paint the pixels in secondTexture that match X and Y of sourceTexture with blue per example
              pixels[x + y * width] = Color.blue;
            }
            else
            {
             //Paint the rest of the pixels with black
             pixels[x + y * width] = Color.black;
            }
   }
}
secondTexture.SetPixels(pixels);
secondTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
secondTexture.Apply();
return secondTexture;
```

So basically, what should happens is that whenever a pixel of the sourceTexture is white color, that pixel in the second texture is changed to blue, and when the pixels in sourceTexture ARE NOT white, the pixels on the secondTexture are black. That´s more or less the idea, but what I keep getting doesn´t matter what´s the sourceTexture colors, all my pixels in the second texture are inmediately black. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetPixels()` returns an array of Color. If you want to get the color of single pixel, use `GetPixel()` instead. In your code try to change `Color pixels2 = source.GetPixels(x, y);`to `Color pixels2 = source.GetPixel(x, y);`

**Update 1:**
Try to test this code. Working perfectly for me.

```
int width = 150;
int height = 150;
Texture2D secondTexture;
public Texture2D source; //texture for a test, add in inspector
public Renderer rend; //Object for a test, add in inspector

      void Start()

    {
      secondTexture = new Texture2D(width, height);

      var pixels = new Color[width * height];
for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
   for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
   {
            Color pixels2 = source.GetPixel(x, y);

            if(pixels2 == Color.white)
            {
              //Paint the pixels in secondTexture that match X and Y of sourceTexture with blue per example
              pixels[x + y * width] = Color.blue;
            }
            else
            {
             //Paint the rest of the pixels with black
             pixels[x + y * width] = Color.black;
            }
   }
}
secondTexture.SetPixels(pixels);
secondTexture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;
secondTexture.Apply();

rend.material.mainTexture = secondTexture;
    }
```

Comment: still getting the same, all pixels are black :S

Comment: So yeah, that´s working, however doing some other test it doesn´t for me, I mean, if I use an imported texture it works fine, but I do need it with procedural texture being the source texture, so I think the problem is that is not set as readable so I can´t access that source texture (the procedural one), if that´s the case, you know how can I enable the read and write? Sry xD I just saw somewhere that procedural texture are not set to readable